# Display multi-page tiff in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, tiff

Is there any way to extract separate streams from an incoming multi-page tiff stream.
I would then pass them to the `DefaultStreamedContent` constructor  and display them with the `<p:graphicImage>`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot display a .tiff file directly via a primefaces-component. You can however display it with plain HTML by using something like this:

```
<embed width=200 height=200
    src="tiffdocument.tif" type="image/tiff"
    negative=yes>
```

The only downside is that you have to provide the .tiff file as a resource, but it would be possible. Also the multiple pages wouldn't be a problem because you could easily combine the two streams to one .tiff file.

Source:
http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html